# Open CV samples prompt for OpenCV Manager download

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

Open CV applications for android prompts me to download and install Open CV Manager...
I just want to know whether there will be a prompt in every application that uses the OpenCV library?If yes is there any way to avoid this?
Thanking you in advance for your valuable efforts

Answer (score 8):

Yes, with opencv 2.4.2 it will prompt IF you do not have the opencv manager installed (yet).

The way to avoid that is explained [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization):

Comment: but it still asking for opencv manager even i use the way which you link

Answer (score 2):

You should read static initialization on opencv.org

Brief:  you add native libraries to your project libs folder.

After in generally or  with_manager style Library loads with ..initAsync(...) method. 
You should change this to initDebug().

Your project runs without needs Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you've worked this out by now but once you've installed the manager you shouldn't get many ( any? ) prompts. See [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/trunk/android/service/doc/Intro.html)

Comment: I just wanted to know whether there is a work around without installing OpenCV Manager.

Comment: Try installing an older version of OpenCV for android. When I had it in my app there was no manager and that was only a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the message you will need to install OpenCV Manager and the appropriate OpenCV binary package before using the application. Otherwise it prompts to "OpenCV Manager package was not found! Try to install it". The following link will help you "[opencv manager package](http://opencv.itseez.com/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html)"